# How to print in GUI not in console in Python

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am practicing a bit, and I have defined several functions in a single file which I imported in my GUI python file that I am trying to make, and the functions work great. However, I made a simple set of buttons for the 8 functions that I created, but I don't know how to print the results in GUI, not in the console. Below is my code, so you can take a look and thank you for understanding. So basically, what is the best way to wrap the code up and utilize GUI.

"functions" is my file where I wrote code for addition, subtraction, random number and other functions as well.

```
from functions import *
import tkinter


window=tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Calculator")

lbl=tkinter.Label(window, text="Choose the operation")
lbl.pack()


btn=tkinter.Button (text="Addition", command=lambda: addition())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn=tkinter.Button (text="Subtraction", command=lambda: subtraction())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn=tkinter.Button (text="Multiplication", command=lambda: multiplication())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn=tkinter.Button (text="Division ", command=lambda: division())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn=tkinter.Button (text="Higher Number ", command=lambda: higher_number())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn=tkinter.Button (text="Rrandom_number ", command=lambda: random_number())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn = tkinter.Button(text="Your Spirit Animal  ", command=lambda: YourSpiritAnimal ())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

btn = tkinter.Button(text="Your Fake Name  ", command=lambda: YourFakeName ())
btn.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)



window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
import functools as ft

root = tk.Tk()

def updateText(l):
    l.config(text = random.randint(0, 999))


l = tk.Label(root)
b = tk.Button(root, text = "updateText()", command = ft.partial(updateText, l))

l.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)
b.pack()
```

A very basic example but this will show you a way how to. I think an OOP approach would be easier for this task.